# Expectation on a Bounded Support

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider $ X \le 0$ be a (continuous/or discrete) random variable with density function $f_X$ having a bounded support, denoted by $supp(f_X)$.

> If $g(t) = \infty $ for $t \in (-\infty,0]$, is the following integral
>   $$
> \int_{-\infty}^0 g(t) \;f_X(t) \; dt = \infty?
> $$

I think it is true. Since $g(.)$ takes value of infinity and for $x \in (-\infty,0] \cap supp(f_X)$, the $f_X$ assures positive probability measure on the set $[-\infty,0)$. Is my thinking correct? or is there any flaws? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The usual way to define multiplication for unsigned measurable functions is $0\cdot\infty = \infty \cdot 0=0$. In this case,
$$
g(t)f_{X}(t)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }f_{X}(t)=0;\\
\infty & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, the question boils down to whether or not $f_{X}(t)$ is zero almost everywhere. Remember, $\int f_{X}=1$.